# Running rake db:migrate without some initializers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, jruby

I am trying to run `jruby -S rake db:migrate`, but I do not want to start up a daemon in `config/initializers` whenever I do a migrate.  Is there a way to do this? Up until now, I have just been moving the daemon file to a file with a .bak extension so that rails doesn't load it when I do the migrate.

I suspect that this is a stupid way of doing things. Is there a better way?

Oh and I am running `jruby` ( if it matters ).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When run:

```
NODAEMON=1 rake db:migrate
```

In initializer:

```
unless ENV['NODAEMON']
# ...
end
```

You can also create separate task for setting NODAEMON, e.g.

```
task :fast_migrate do
  ENV['NODAEMON'] = '1' # or just set global variable, or some config
  Rake['db:migrate'].invoke
end
```